# How do I install the php_gd2 extension in MAMP on a Mac?

Tags: php, mamp

I'm running MAMP 1.7.2 on a Mac and I'd like to install the extension php_gd2.  How do I do this?  I know that on Windows using WAMP I'd simply select the `php_gd2` entry in the extensions menu to activate it.  How is it done when using MAMP? I know that I can do it using MacPorts but I'd prefer not to make any changes to my default OS X PHP installation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't need to install the extension.  I have 1.7.2 installed and running right now and it has GD bundled (2.0.34 compatible).

From the MAMP start page, click on phpinfo and you should see a GD section.

Comment: MAMP PRO Mac, finally found it under Sidebar > Hosts > myhost.test > General > PHP Version > and then clicking that little right arrow.

Answer (score 0):

php.ini for MAMP 1.7.2 is located:
if using **php5**, here: **/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5/php.ini**
if **php4**, here: **/Applications/MAMP/conf/php4/php.ini**

hope that helps...